# When extra turtle is created turtle-own variable value increases when it shouldn't

Tags: netlogo

I have a number of global variables where values are set and a number of turtle-own variables where an initial value is set but change by the associated global variable once the model beings to run.

For example:

```
globals [dis-id]

turtles-own [identity]

to determine-parameters
  set dis-id -1
  ask turtles [
  set identity 0
end
```

So when a turtle acts its identity goes up or down 1 depending on how successful an action has been.

So say an action was successful, identity should move from 0 to -1. If it is successful again it will move -1 to -2 etc. and vice-versa for failure 0 to 1, 1 to 2 etc.

**My problem is that for every turtle that is added to the model (either created from the observer when running or setup procedure) this amount of change increases.**

1 turtle  0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3 (correct + 1)

2 turtles 0 to 2, 2 to 4, 4 to 6 (incorrect + 2)

3 turtles 0 to 3, 3 to 6, 6 to 9 (incorrect + 3)
etc.

If the global variable is -6 instead of 1 i.e.

```
globals [dis-id]

turtle-own [identity]

to determine-parameters
  set dis-id -6
  ask turtles [
  set identity 0
end
```

The same pattern occurs

1 turtle  0 to 6, 6 to 12, 12 to 18 (correct + 6)

2 turtles 0 to 12, 12 to 24, 24 to 36 (incorrect + 12)

3 turtles 0 to 18, 18 to 36, 36 to 54 (incorrect + 18)
etc.

The procedure/calculation to determine identity is

```
to succeed
  ask turtles [
    if outcome > expectation [
      set identity (identity - dis-id)]
   ]
 end

to fail
  if outcome < expectation [
    ask turtles [
      set identity (identity - dis-id)]
    ]
end
```

This problem is consistent for every turtle-own variable calculated the same way.

I have attempted many fixes to no avail.
Any help with this would be much appreciated! 
If any further explanation or code is needed to help problem solve this please let me know as I'm not sure how much or how little code I should put here. FYI the actual code is quite long.

**UPDATE**
the bit of code that was the problem was

```
to dothething
  ask turtles [
    if X >= Y [
        succeed
        fail]
   ]
```

Thank you to JenB for pointing this out!

Comment: Can you please show us the code that calls the succeed and fail procedures. I think you probably have something like `ask turtles [ succeed ]` but then NetLogo gets to the succeed procedure and runs `ask turtles` again.

Comment: Hi JenB, This was exactly it. Thank you! I fear I could not see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it out.